# Notation for the set $\{1,2,..,k\}$

Tags: reference-request, notation, integers

I often find myself using the set $\{1,2,..,k\}$, sometimes on multiple occasions in a sentence. I've been told that $[k]$ is a short notation for this, but have never seen that in use. Could someone refer me to a textbook-like source that uses this notation so that I may cite it.

Comment: I think [Norman Biggs](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/personal/norman/) uses it in [Discrete Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Edition-Norman-Biggs/dp/0198507178), but I'm not sure. There's always [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_notation#Metaphor_in_denoting_sets) (third paragraph in the linked section). [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287251/about-math-notation-the-set-of-the-nth-natural-numbers).

Comment: Some times it is $\overline{1..k}$

Comment: Personally, I like to use $[|1,n|]$

Comment: I usually use either $\bar k=\{0,1,...,k\}$ and $\bar k^*=\{1,...,k\}$ or $[\![1,k]\!]$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521437/standard-notation-for-the-set-of-integers-0-1-n-1 and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287251/about-math-notation-the-set-of-the-nth-natural-numbers.

Comment: Briggs write two brackets to denote different types of equivalence relations, but I did not find the usage $[k]=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ in his Discrete Mathematics. I like the $[|1,k|]$ and $[\![1,k]\!]$ options. They are suggestive and flexible. But I would not want to adopt anything that is not already established. At least the $[k]$ notation is on Wikipedia, although for a reference I would only use a text in print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very famous textbook using the notation $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is *Enumerative Combinatorics* (Volume 1) by Richard Stanley. It's in the list of notation at the beginning of the book, and is first used in Example 1.1.16.

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you.